# When I am keeping the IST as timezone i am getting error but when i have kept GMT it is working Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If i have Oct 06 09:42:21 IST 2020 and Mar 05 06:49:10 2021 IST how to compare both of them when they are in strings like Mar and Oct.Like for date we can take the values and compare easily but for months how can we compare if it is in this format.

```
from datetime import datetime

s1 = 'Oct 06 09:42:21 IST 2020'
d1 = datetime.strptime(s1, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
print(d1)

s2 = 'Oct 06 09:42:26 2020 IST'
d2 = datetime.strptime(s2, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z')
print(d2)

print(d1 < d2)
```

Comment: What kind of comparison? Can you make a proper example?

Comment: how to compare the months if it is in Jan,Oct format

Comment: see https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime. This will help you to convert the strings you have into datetime objects

Comment: You should never internally manage date/time values as strings. Handling timezones is not trivial, for example. Convert them to real date/time objects first.

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime('Oct 06 09:42:21 GMT 2020', '%b %d %X %Z %Y')` → `datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 6, 9, 42, 21)`. From there you can use all the fancy features of a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the strings into `datetime.datetime` objects via [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime

s1 = 'Oct 06 09:42:21 GMT 2020'
d1 = datetime.strptime(s1, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')

s2 = 'Mar 05 06:49:10 2021 GMT'
d2 = datetime.strptime(s2, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z')

print(d1 < d2)
```

prints `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.strptime` to turn the date strings into `datetime.datetime` objects, which you can compare. Please note, your two example strings have different formats (one has the year before the time zone name, the other in reversed order).

```
from datetime import datetime

strings = [
    "Oct 06 09:42:21 GMT 2020",
    "Mar 05 06:49:10 GMT 2021"
]

dates = [datetime.strptime(string, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y") for string in strings]
```